# Does openCV SurfFeatureDetector unnecessarily extract descriptors internally?

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, surf

I just wondered, if using a SurfFeatureDetector to detect keypoints and a SurfDescriptorExtractor to extract the SURF descriptors (see code below as described [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/trunk/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_description/feature_description.html#feature-description)) wouldn't extract the descriptors twice.

```
  SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );

  std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
  detector.detect( img, keypoints ); //detecting keypoints, extracting descriptors without returning them

  SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
  Mat descriptors;

  extractor.compute( img, keypoints, descriptors ); // extracting descriptors a second time
```

The openCV documentation says, those 2 classes are wrappers for the SURF() class.
The `SURF::operator()` is overloaded, one version taking just a keypoint vector, the other one additionally taking a vector for the descriptors.
What intrigues me... both then call the `cvExtractSURF()` function, which seems to extract the descriptors, no matter what... (I did not dive too deep into the C code as I find it hard to understand, so maybe I'm wrong)
But this would mean that the `SurfFeatureDetector` would extract descriptors without returning them. Using the `SurfDescriptorExtractor` in the next step just does it a second time, which seems very inefficient to me. But am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can be assured that detector does not actually compute the descriptors. The key statement to look at is line 687 of surf.cpp `if( !descriptors ) continue;` Features are not computed during detection, the way it should be. This kind of architecture is most likely due to the fact that surf code was "added" to OpenCV after it was designed/developed to work by itself.

As a background: note that detector and feature extractors are different things. You first "detect" points using SurfFeatureDetector where *local* features are extracted (using SurfDescriptorExtractor). The snippet you have is a good guide.

Comment: I know the detector and the extractor are two different things. Otherwise, I wouldn't ask...  But looking at the source code I found out that both internally call cvExtractSurf(). And I couldn't find the place, where the descriptor computation is skipped in the first case. Maybe someone can point out the line of code where that's happening to prove me wrong... and I really hope to be proven wrong!

Comment: Can you provide the line no. where you see cvExtractSurf() being called from the detector?

Comment: in OpenCV 2.2.0 source code:
features2d -> detectors.cpp:
line 442: surf(grayImage,mask,keypoints) is called
this should refer to:
features2d->surf.cpp:
line 960: void SURF::operator()(const Mat& img, const Mat& mask,
                      vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints) const

then, in line 968:
cvExtractSURF(&_img, pmask, &kp.seq, 0, storage, *(const CvSURFParams*)this, 0);

Then it goes into C code, which is hard to read (for me)

Comment: The code is indeed somewhat difficult to understand, but be assured that detector does *not* actually compute the descriptors. The key statement to look at is line 687 of surf.cpp 'if( !descriptors ) continue;' All is well -- the way it should be.

Comment: Ok, I didn't dive that deep into the code, but it seems you're right :) I was just worried if I should use the Detector or if I should better do the detection and extraction in one go with the SURF class. Can you edit your answer so I can accept it?